# Python: How to compare the length of several strings which are parameters?

Tags: python, compare, string-length

What I want to get is a function which compare the length of several parameters, these parameters are strings.

Something like (pseudocode):

```
def check_length(*args):
    if args[0] == args[1] == ... == args[n]:
        do_something
```

So far, I develop the following code, but I'm sure that there must exists a better way since this is a paired comparison:

```
def checkLen(*args):
    arg_list = []
    for index_A in range(len(args)):
        for index_B in range(len(args)):
            if index_B > index_A:
                if len(args[index_A]) == len(args[index_B]):
                    pass
                else:
                    raise Exception
```

Thanks to all. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
def check_length(*args):
    if all(args[0] == _arg for _arg in args[1:]):
        do_something
```

You can apply whatever logic you want in the generator expression, if any `args[0] == _arg` evaluates to False then all will *short-circuit* or else evaluate to True. If you want to check all the lengths:

```
if all(len(args[0]) == len(_arg) for _arg in args[1:]):
```

If you want to raise an error if any length is not the same check if they are `not all(...`:

```
def check_length(*args):
    if not all(len(args[0]) == len(_arg) for _arg in args[1:]):
        raise ValueError("All parameters must be the same length.")
    do_something
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a single regular for-loop.

```
def checkLen(*args):
    match = True
    for i in range(1,len(args)):
        if(len(args[i-1]) != len(args[i])):
            match = False    
    if match:
        do_something()
```

Comment: This logic is not the same as in the question.  Yours will `do_something()` every time `len(args[i-1]) == len(args[i])` whereas the original question asked about doing something only if they are all the same.

Comment: Ah, whoops. The general idea still applies though. I'll fix that.